# Why does &mut T seem to behave like a Copy type?

Tags: reference, rust, move-semantics

I am trying to better understand move semantics and the behavior of `Copy` types in Rust.

I know that `&mut` T is not `Copy`, as explained [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html#when-cant-my-type-be-copy), because copying `&mut T` would create an aliased mutable reference. But then I do not understand the behavior of the following program:

```
fn my_ref_mut(the_ref_mut: &mut Vec<i32>) {
    println!("{:?}", the_ref_mut);
}

fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();
    let r: &mut Vec<i32> = &mut v;
    my_ref_mut(r);
    my_ref_mut(r); // Should not this be an `use after move` error?
}
```

I would have expected the program above not to compile because of an [E0382](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0382): `use of moved value` error. The `r` variable behaves as if it is `Copy`. I have tried to better understand the situation with the following program. It gives two different compilation errors, depending on whether the types are explicitly specified (for me to be sure I get the expected types):

```
fn my_ref_mut(the_ref_mut: &mut Vec<i32>) {
    println!("{:?}", the_ref_mut);
}

fn my_ref(the_ref: &Vec<i32>) {
    println!("{:?}", the_ref);
}

fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();
    {
        let r: &mut Vec<i32> = &mut v;
        my_ref_mut(r);
        my_ref_mut(r);
    }
    {
        let r1: &mut Vec<i32> = &mut v;
        my_ref_mut(r1);
        let r2 = r1;
        my_ref_mut(r1);
    }
    {
        let r: &Vec<i32> = &v;
        my_ref(r);
        my_ref(r);
    }
    {
        let r1: &Vec<i32> = &v;
        my_ref(r1);
        let r2: &Vec<i32> = r1;
        my_ref(r1);
    }
}
```

The error is self explanatory:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `*r1`
  --> src/main.rs:20:20
   |
19 |         let r2 = r1;
   |             -- value moved here
20 |         my_ref_mut(r1);
   |                    ^^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `r1` has type `&mut std::vec::Vec<i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I would have expected it to be `use of moved value: r1`, not `*r1`, because I have moved the reference, not the value itself.

By changing line 19 to `let r2: &mut Vec<i32> = r1;`, thus specifying the type of `r2` explicitly, the error becomes [E0499](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0499):

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*r1` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:20:20
   |
19 |         let r2: &mut Vec<i32> = r1;
   |                                 -- first mutable borrow occurs here
20 |         my_ref_mut(r1);
   |                    ^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
21 |     }
   |     - first borrow ends here
```

This error also seems wrong to me, because the first borrow of `*r1` should be the one on line 17 (`let r1: &mut Vec<i32> = &mut v;`). I know about autoref and `Deref` coercion, but from what I believe, they are not applicable here.

My conclusion is that `&T` is `Copy`, as expected and as the second example above demonstrates, but I cannot say the same thing about `&mut T`.

I would like someone to explain to me the compilation errors and why `&mut T` sometimes seems to behave like being `Copy`. Is it also possible for this to be a compiler bug? My toolchain is:

```
stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.25.0 (84203cac6 2018-03-25)
```